# how to apply custom font in spinner in ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have set spinner in actionbar using  `bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);`

and then set

```
dropdownValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sortby_array);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.sortby_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
```

Now i want to change font style .. so any one can help me plz

Comment: use SpannableString http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Answer (score 2):

Make a folder font inside your assets folder and put the font inside that folder.Hope this  works for you

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.sortby_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) {

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

             Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your font name here");
             ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

             return v;
     }


     public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
              View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

             Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ your font name here");
             ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

             return v;
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 mLocations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

create this R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with a `SpinnerAdapter`. See code example:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (view instanceof TextView) {

            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/hattori.ttf");

            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            ((TextView) view).setTypeface(tf);
            ((TextView) view).setTextSize(16);
        }
        return view;
    }


}
```

Edit: this was not in ActionBar so not sure if it works the same.